# Native C Programming on Microsoft Windows 7 without an IDE

Tags: c, windows

Is there any way to write, compile and run C programs from the Windows Command Prompt? I mean just like what is possible from the Linux Terminal using the gcc compiler.

Specifically, I want to know how does Microsoft's "cl.exe" C compiler works. How do I install it? Is it possible to simply write a C Program in a text editor like notepad, then compile it using cl.exe from Command Prompt and run it from there?

Note: I do not want any other kind of C programming solutions on Windows, like using 3rd party compilers like Turbo-C, DevC++, etc, or using Unix emulators like MingGW, etc, or even IDE solutions like Visual Studio, Eclipse, etc. I already know about these.

What I want is to use the native Windows platform for console application programming using Microsoft's own cl.exe compiler and standard Windows libraries. Is it possible?

Apologies if I sound too complicated :)

Comment: It's exactly the same on Windows as Linux.

Comment: Hmm, if you used an IDE then you would not be asking this question.  Do not skimp on thoroughly reading the command line option documentation, there are a lot of goodies that make diagnosing bugs a lot easier.  Goodies like Edit+Continue and minimal rebuilds are not available without an IDE.  The debugger is integrated in the IDE, you'll have to look for another one.

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/610ecb4h%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) explains how to use the cl.exe command line options. You may need to set your PATH variable correctly for this to work.

Answer (score 2):

You ask and answer your own question - there is nothing to it more than downloading the SDK, and using the developer command line to compile a file (`cl hello.c`). By using the shortcut to the developer command line, your PATH and other environment variables are correctly set and you're ready to start compiling immediately.

This is the [full cl documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/610ecb4h%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).